# A different method of evaluating $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin^3(x)\cdot\sin(x+\alpha})}\,dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I was practicing indefinite integrals and came to this integral:

$$
       \int\frac {1}{\sqrt{\sin^3(x)\cdot\sin(x+\alpha})}\,dx.
$$

Everywhere there is only one method given for solving this question 
which involves dividing numerator and denominator by $\sin^2(x).$

However, I wanted to know if there was any other method for solving this or not?

Comment: Divide numerator & denominator by $\cos^2x$ or $\sin^2x$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I wanted to know if there was any other method for solving this or not ??

Answer (score 6):

So you want to find another method here is one

$$I={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\sin^\frac{3}{2}\left(x\right)\sqrt{\sin\left(x+a\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$I={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\sin^\frac{3}{2}\left(x\right)\sqrt{\cos\left(a\right)\sin\left(x\right)+\sin\left(a\right)\cos\left(x\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\sin\left(x\right)=\dfrac{1}{\csc\left(x\right)}$$
$$\cos\left(x\right)=\dfrac{\cot\left(x\right)}{\csc\left(x\right)}$$

$$I={\displaystyle\int}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin\left(a\right)\cot\left(x\right)+\cos\left(a\right)}}\right)}}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\csc^2\left(x\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$I={\displaystyle\int}-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\left(-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin\left(a\right)\cot\left(x\right)+\cos\left(a\right)}}\right)}}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\csc^2\left(x\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Substitute $u=\cot\left(x\right)$ Thus $\mathrm{d}x=-\dfrac{1}{\csc^2\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u$

$$I=-{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin\left(a\right)u+\cos\left(a\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

$$v=\sin\left(a\right)u+\cos\left(a\right)$$
$$\mathrm{d}u=\dfrac{1}{\sin\left(a\right)}\,\mathrm{d}v$$
$$I=-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-3}{\dfrac{1}{\sin\left(a\right)}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{v}}\,\mathrm{d}v$$

$$I=-\dfrac{2\sqrt{v}}{\sin\left(a\right)}$$
$$I=-\dfrac{2\sqrt{\sin\left(a\right)u+\cos\left(a\right)}}{\sin\left(a\right)}$$

$$u=\cot\left(x\right)$$
$$I=-\dfrac{2\sqrt{\sin\left(a\right)\cot\left(x\right)+\cos\left(a\right)}}{\sin\left(a\right)}$$

$$I=-\dfrac{2\sqrt{\sin\left(a\right)\cot\left(x\right)+\cos\left(a\right)}}{\sin\left(a\right)}+C$$

Comment: i did not get how you got this $$I={\displaystyle\int}-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\left(-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin\left(a\right)\cot\left(x\right)+\cos\left(a\right)}}\right)}}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\csc^2\left(x\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: I wrote it like that because I wanted to use $$\mathrm{d}x=-\dfrac{1}{\csc^2\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

you can simply write that
$$I={\displaystyle\int}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin\left(a\right)\cot\left(x\right)+\cos\left(a\right)}}\right)}}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\csc^2\left(x\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$-1\cdot-1=1$$

Comment: I also edited that the answer so you can understand what I am trying to do here

Comment: no I mean how did you get this step  $$I={\displaystyle\int}-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\left(-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin\left(a\right)\cot\left(x\right)+\cos\left(a\right)}}\right)}}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\csc^2\left(x\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$  from this step $$I={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\sin^\frac{3}{2}\left(x\right)\sqrt{\cos\left(a\right)\sin\left(x\right)+\sin\left(a\right)\cos\left(x\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ ?

Comment: take $\sin(x)$ common from  $$\sqrt{\cos\left(a\right)\sin\left(x\right)+\sin\left(a\right)\cos\left(x\right)}$$
$$\sin^{1/2}(x)\sqrt{\cos\left(a\right)+\sin\left(a\right)\cot\left(x\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! :)

Comment: is it different from the first method in which you divide by $\sin^{2}x$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82736/discussion-between-jim-and-deepesh-meena).